# Why does this transformation solve this system of equations?

Tags: linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Often when considering an equation, if one can recognize any familiar structures in the equation, one can simplify it with a transformation; for example if one has a symmetric equation that is also the equation for an ellipse, but it has an $xy$ term, then it is probably an ellipse rotated by $45^\circ$, so the transformation $x = s - t, y = s + t$ would be appropriate, since it rotates the points by $45^\circ$ (it also scales them).

Consider the following system of equations:
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1, \qquad y^2 + z^2 = 1, \qquad z^2 + x^2 = 1
$$
This system can be solved using various methods, but below is seen one:

> Make the substitution $x = u + v - s, y = v + s - u, z = s + u - v$.
>
> Expanding each square, this reduces to the following system:
>
> \begin{align}
> s^2 + u^2 + v^2 - 2uv &= \frac12 \\
> s^2 + u^2 + v^2 - 2vs &= \frac12 \\
> s^2 + u^2 + v^2 - 2su &= \frac12 \\
> \end{align}
>   Now this implies $uv = vs = su$. Now there are two cases: they are all equal or exactly two of them are zero.
>
> If all of them are equal, we obtain $s^2 = \frac12$, and $x=y=z=s$, yielding two solutions to the original system. If two of them are zero, then call the last one for $t$. Any of the three equations will reduce to $t^2 = \frac12$, and this yields six solutions to the original system.
>
> Together these are the $8$ solutions in total to the system gained by $x,y,z \in \{\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\}$.

Admittedly there are much cleaner solutions such as:
$$(x^2+y^2) - (y^2+z^2) + (z^2+x^2) = 1 - 1 + 1$$
But that's not the focus of this question. I found this solution while trying to transform the problem into something harder.

The question is: Like I explained with the ellipse, can one explain why the transformation solved the problem by considering what transformation the transformation corresponds to? What happens to the point $(x,y,z)$ when it is turned into $(s,u,v)$ by the transformation? And what happens to the three cylinders represented by the original system of equations when transformed with the given transformation.

Maybe the original system of equations was really just that easy and the transformation didn't do much on that accord.

Comment: Hmm, that seems more complex than is required for this problem. It works, but I'd just add the three equations to get $x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{3}{2}$ then subtract and you get $x^2=y^2=z^2=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I know, and even mentioned something very similar to your solution in the question.

Comment: Why don't you set $X=x^2,Y=y^2,Z=z^2$ yielding a very simple linear system:   $X+Y=1,Y+Z=1,Z+X=1$, and just have to check that the solutions are positive ?...

Comment: The question isn't really about what is the best way to solve the equation, but more about what is the transformation I mentioned, and what does the transformation do to the cylinders represented by the equations.